# how to upload .ply file using ng2-file-upload in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ply-file-format

i am trying to upload various file using ng2-file-upload and here i am able to upload all the file types like png,jpg etc except **.ply** file so how can i upload the file with that extension

below is my code

```
  imga = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/soft-scraps/256/Button-Upload-icon.png";

  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public selectedFilesArray = [];
  private selectedFile;



    public selectFile(e: any): void {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement || e.currentTarget;
    var value = target.innerHTML;
    this.selectedFile = value;
    this.selectAll = true;
    this.selectedFilesArray = [];
    this.selectedFilesArray.push(this.selectedFile);

  }
  public fileOverBase(e: any): void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

    public selectAllFiles(e: any): void {

    this.selectedFilesArray = [];
    if (e.target.checked) {

      this.selectAll = true;

      for (var item in this.uploader.queue) {
        this.selectedFilesArray.push(this.uploader.queue[item].file.name);
      }




    }


  }
```

below is my stackblitz url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6cbrj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ply` is not a recognized MIME type by `ng2-file-upload`. You can find all the supported MIME types in the source code here:

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/blob/development/src/file-upload/file-type.class.ts

as you can see, the content type is set to `application` for non-listed file extensions.

Comment: OK so how can we customise the plugin for custom requirements i mean adding it

Comment: Three choices: 1. Post an issue on GitHub and ask the author to include your MIME type. 2. Submit a Pull Request to the project on GitHub to include the MIME type yourself. 3. Fork the project and maintain a custom version by editing the source yourself (not recommended).